# Как отсортировать массив у которых значение 0 и другое значение?

Tags: php

```
$arr = array(
    1 => 0, 
    2 => 5, 
    3 => 10, 
    4 => 0, 
    5 => 0, 
    6 => 8,
);
```

У тех у кого значение 0 в один массив, у тех у кого значение не 0 в отельный массив возможно ли это сделать ?

Comment: foreach + if = profit

Comment: https://ideone.com/UQDxAf

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
1 => 0,
2 => 5,
3 => 10,
4 => 0,
5 => 0,
6 => 8,
);

$arr0 = array_filter($arr, function ($element) {
    return $element == 0;
});

$arrNot0 = array_filter($arr, function ($element) {
    return $element != 0;
});
```